# Can I use the native map function to map a list of tuples to one of its element in a Jinja template?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

Let's say that I have a variable

```
t = [(1, 'hello'), (2, 'world')]
```

What I want is to map this to a new list containing only the second element of the tuples, in a Jinja template:

```
{% set s = t | map(...) | list %}
```

The variable `s` should be `['hello', 'world']`.

Is this possible in some way without using a custom filter?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, it's the `attribute` method:

```
{% set t = [(1, 'hello'), (2, 'world')] %}
{% set t1 = t|map(attribute=1)|list %}
{{ t1 }}
```

Comment: That is soo underdocumented...

Answer (score 0):

Jinja engine is limited in terms of python expressions as per following [quote](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates) from Jinja documentation:

> ... 
>   Jinja2 neither allows you to put arbitrary Python code into
>   templates nor does it allow all Python expressions. ***The operators are
>   limited to the most common ones and more advanced expressions such as
>   list comprehensions and generator expressions are not supported***. This
>   keeps the template engine easier to maintain and templates more
>   readable.

That's being said, you should do most of data processing in actual Python code or of you are using JS, just pass it as variables and process it with JS then render it and leave templates as clean as possible for easier maintenance.

Edit: Solution inspired from Jinja's docs:

Probably, this might work for you, which I found on [Jinja's docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#literals):

```
<ul>
{% for nb, word in t %}
    <li><a href="">{{ word }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```